gRPC Constructor for CallOptions C#
Is there any behavior difference in the following two callOptions?
var callOptions1 = new CallOptions(headers: new Metadata());
var callOptions2 = new CallOptions();
I am using "Grpc.Net.Client" Version="2.56.0"
I assume the behavior is the same. Am I right?

The functional difference here is a null vs non-null value of the options' .Headers value; both of these are valid, but using a new Metadata() means a small additional allocation; whether that matters is contextual. If you explicitly mean to express a non-null but empty set of headers: there is also Metadata.Empty, so a third option is:
var callOptions3 = new CallOptions(headers: Metadata.Empty);

For all three options: no headers are sent.
